# Is it possible to define a timezone on Sequelize.NOW?

Tags: javascript, date, sequelize.js

Hello I define my model for two dates :

```
createdAt:  { type: Sequelize.DATE, defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW },
updatedAt:  { type: Sequelize.DATE, defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW },
```

But im getting an error with GTM. I think i need to define the GTM-5 time zone

Comment: can you share your database config file, which database are you using?

Comment: try this : new Date().getTime()

Comment: Hey! Of course I'm getting a MYSQL database connected without any special información like timezone. Should I add it?